# Regular Expression for index.php redirect (but a bit more complicated!)

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello and thanks for looking at this.  I have an issue in that I need to redirect:
www.thisdomain.com/index.php
to:
www.thisdomain.com/

BUT...

this is complicated by the fact that I have two index.php files.  One here:
www.thisdomain.com/index.php
and one here:
www.thisdomain.com/a_forum/a_forum_submission/index.php

So, the normal 301 redirect I would use is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.thisdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that this will redirect the lower level index.php as well, right back up to the route which is not desired.

So, what I want to achieve is redirecting www.thisdomain.com/index.php to the root, but WITHOUT redirecting www.thisdomain.com/a_forum/a_forum_submission/index.php to the root.

If you can help me out, I'd really appreciate it.  I've tried everything I know of, but my regular expression knowledge is letting me down.

Thanks again,

D

Answer (score 0):

Take out the wildcard match expression `(.*)`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.thisdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Should do what you are looking for. With this, you may not even need the `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 0):

The easier way that I think of solving is creating a .htaccess file inside www.thisdomain.com/a_forum/a_forum_submission/ overwriting that rewritecond or deactivating the rewrite module.

Comment: `.htaccess` files *suck*. The webserveer has to parse them, everytime it serves a file.

Comment: I agree, but a lot of webservers providers don't give you the option.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://www.thisdomain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

No need for the rewrite condition, though.

Have a nice day.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*) http://www.thisdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]`  
 or  
 `RewriteRule ^index\.php http://www.thisdomain.co.uk/ [R=301,L,QSA]` can be better for passing url strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.thisdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*) http://www.thisdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```